# "This formula is missing a range reference or a defined name" Excel error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I recently wrote a formula to arrange an Excel list that was in a .csv format to make it more readable, and I'm getting an unusual error. It says "This formula is missing a range reference or a defined name." I've checked through my formula and can't seem to find anything wrong, so if someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
=IF(EXACT(MID(A2,LEN(A2)-1,2),";;"), MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),1,FIND(";;",MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))-1),IF(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)>2,MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";""",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND("#",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+1)+2,MID(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),1,LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-LEN(CONCAT(""";",IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",LEFT(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-1))),LEFT(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-1),RIGHT(LEFT(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-1),LEN(LEFT(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-1))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-1),";","~",LEN(LEFT(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))),LEN(MID(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))),FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))+2,LEN(MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))-FIND(";",MID(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))),FIND(";",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",A2),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1))))))))-1),";",""))))))))-1)),MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1),1,LEN(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1))-LEN(CONCAT(";",IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1))),MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1),RIGHT(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1),LEN(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1),";","~",LEN(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-FIND(";",MID(A2,FIND(";",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))-1),";","")))))))))))
```

*Edit: Desired output is string `message` in the comma-delimited string `;userdata;date;message;attachment(if there is one);`. These are normal conversational messages, and commas appear frequently, which cuts off the message in the current cell and splits the rest of it to the cell 1 column to the left.*

*Example:*

```
<A1>;james-1029;2018-09-10 1:40 PM;hi guys;hello.png;
<A2>;nope-8888;2018-09-10 1:41 PM;"Why
<B2> hello
<C2> james";;
<A3>;username-7473;2018-09-10 1:45 PM;hey to you as well;;
```

*Desired Output:*

```
<D1>hi guys
<D2>Why, hello, james
<D3>hey to you as well
```

Comment: Your formula is over 23k characters long. Are you sure this code makes sense?

Comment: That (terrifying) formula looks to be too long for Excel's 8,192 character limit.

Comment: hi, it seems that your formula has **more than 23000 char's**.. i think that there is a maximum of 16384 char by formula. u have to simplify or break the formula in pieces... good luck

Comment: That's a pretty monster formula. Is there some test data and expected output please to go with it. It will aid in debugging as I, for example, am getting #Value error and, as mentioned, the formula length is suspect. There might be a better way.

Comment: Notice that the desired output is between the "PM;" and next ";" character. Likewise, the merged values (Why, hello, james) are within the same row. So basically, the desired output would want one line item per row. You may try to draft a formula using `IF`, `CONCATENATE`, `MID` and `FIND` functions, among others, for each row. I don't think this would even reach 1000 characters in the formula. Expanding further your sample set provided, we may be able to find certain patterns we can use as basis of a solution.